# Columns out by quantity specified

Tags: excel, vba

I just need a simple solution to shift data any data out by the number of columns specified in each row.

For example:

```
shift                                   
2           x   x   x   x           
4                   x   x   x       
5                       x   x   x   x
```

so for 2 the first 2 columns are empty and the data is shifted to cell 3
for 4 the first 4 columns are empty and the data is shifted out to cell 5.

Comment: some of the data can be hundreds of columns across and there are hundreds of rows that's why I need this help..

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you clarify or add an image of the expected outcome?

Comment: do you actually want `vba` for this? If so, you'll need to provide the code you have written to try and accomplish this. SO isn't a "write the code for me, please" website.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman fighting the good fight :)  Normally I'd comment the same an not answer, but given that writing the code to solve it took all of 30 seconds, I thought I might as well add it in case someone else is searching for the same solution.  I swear I'm not trying to undermine the system! ;)

Comment: guys I am new to macros and trying to learn it .. not trying to abuse the sys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with:

[image]

Running this:

```
Sub Kolumator()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long
    Dim K As Long, j As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        K = Cells(i, 1).Value
        Cells(i, 1).Clear
        For j = 1 To K - 1
            Cells(i, 1).Insert shift:=xlToRight
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

Comment: thanks so much .. and thanks to everyone as well for the help !!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As range
Dim cell As range


Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set rng = range("A1", ws.range("A1").End(xlDown))

For Each cell In rng
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To cell.Value

        cell.Insert xlShiftToRight

    Next i

Next cell


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveCells()

Dim cell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

For Each cell In ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
Range(Cells(cell.row, 2), Cells(cell.row, 2).End(xlToRight)).Cut Range(Cells(cell.row, 2), Cells(cell.row, 2).End(xlToRight)).Offset(0, cell.Value)
Next cell

End Sub
```